# Is it possible to remove the working directory from a dockerfile

Tags: docker

I have specified a working directory in my Dockerfile using the WORKDIR command.

When my docker is done building and and I launch it, it starts in that working directory.

I know that I can specify a second WORKDIR command and then the docker will start in that directory when it is launched.

How do I delete the original working directory from within the dockerfile?

Comment: I think you simply can another `WORKDIR` before `CMD/ENTRYPOINT` command. But why do you want to remove the first WORKDIR?

Comment: the first workdir contains scripts and other temporary artifacts that should be cleaned up.  the user of the container doesn't need that stuff.

Comment: i just added another RUN command to delete the folder and that worked.  this is strange because i read other stackoverflow posts which stated that it did not work for those users.

Comment: I think the safe way is after the second `workdir`, you can add `run rm -rf THE_FIRST_WORKDIR`

Comment: Also consider a [multi-stage build](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) that can `COPY --from=` the first stage into the final stage; this will result in a smaller final image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and realised that the issue was that I first needed to change WORKDIR to a different directory, and then after that I could delete the directory.

```
WORKDIR C:/install/oracle/client
...do some stuff here
WORKDIR C:/web/
#now I can delete the previous WORKDIR
RUN Remove-Item -Path "C:/install/oracle/*" -Recurse -Force
```